# OpenCL bad get_global_id output

Tags: gpu, opencl

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication, but `get_global_id` returns incorrect values.
This is the host code (n, m, TILE_SIZE = 4):

```
int dimention = 2;
size_t global_item_size[] = {n, m};
size_t local_item_size[] = {TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE};

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, dimention, NULL, global_item_size, local_item_size, 0, NULL, &perf_event);
```

And part of the kernel:

```
kernel void mul_tile(uint n, uint m, uint k, global const float *a, global const float *b, global float *c) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    size_t j = get_global_id(1);
    
    printf("aa %i %i\n", i, j);
}
```

This code prints this:

```
aa 0 0
aa 1 0
aa 2 0
aa 3 0
aa 0 0
aa 1 0
aa 2 0
aa 3 0
aa 0 0
aa 1 0
aa 2 0
aa 3 0
aa 0 0
aa 1 0
aa 2 0
aa 3 0
```

After some time I realized that `get_global_id(0)` returns correct index when I call it the first time and zero when I call it the second time:

```
kernel void mul_tile(uint n, uint m, uint k, global const float *a, global const float *b, global float *c) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    size_t j = get_global_id(0);
    
    printf("aa %i %i\n", i, j);
}
```

So, this kernel prints the same thing.
In some cases `get_global_id(2)` returns 2-nd dimension indexes. But when I just rename variables it starts printing zeroes.
This problem looks like some driver bug. I use GeForce GT 745M, Ubuntu 20.04 and recommended drivers(nvidia-driver-440).

Comment: Are you sure your `printf` formatting string is correct? `%i` doesn't necessarily seem right for `size_t`. I'm not sure if OpenCL supports `%zi` but you could also just make your variables `uint`.

Comment: Thank you. This actually helped. But on Intel graphic card my code works fine and I don`t understand why(probably this case not regulated by OpenCL standard).

Comment: It probably depends whether size_t is defined as 32-bit (uint) or 64-bit (ulong) on that device